# csvに記録がされないです。

Tags: python, python3

日経平均株価をスクレイピングして記録するプログラムを作りたいのですが、以下のプログラムだとcsvに記録がされません。なぜでしょうか？
以下のプログラムは[この記事](https://qiita.com/Azunyan1111/items/9b3d16428d2bcc7c9406)を参考にしてPython3用に改良したものです。

```
import  urllib.request, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import time

time_flag = True
while True:
    if datetime.now().minute != 59:
        time.sleep(58)
        continue
    f = open('nikkei_heiki.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    while datetime.now().second != 59:
        time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(1)
csv_list = []

time_ = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

csv_list.append(time_)
url = "http://www.nikkei.com/markets/kabu/"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
span = soup.find_all("span")
nikkei_heikin = ""

for tag in span:
    try:
        string_ = tag.get("class").pop(0)
        if string_ in "mkc-stock_prices":
        nikkei_heikin = tag.string
        break
    except:
        pass


    print (time_, nikkei_heikin)
    csv_list.append(nikkei_heikin)
    writer.writerow(csv_list)
    f.close()
```

Comment: 元記事のコードとインデントがかなり異なっていますが、質問文に転記する際の書き間違いでしょうか？

Comment: "span = soup.find_all("span")"で得られた結果は、どうなっていますか？　"try:"の下に"print(tag)"のコードを追加して、確認してみてください。　CSVファイルに書き込むコードに問題は無さそうなので、そもそも書き込むデータが作られていない可能性を確認したほうが良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問に記載のコードでは、毎時59分でないと動作しませんが、それではデバッグをすることが難しいので、日経平均株価をスクレイピング部分を関数にした方がいいです。以下のように関数にすると、インデントがおかしいだけで質問に記載のもので動作します。ただし、`f = open('nikkei_heiki.csv', 'a')`とファイルをオープンするコードは、`try finally`を使うか`with`構文で使うかしないと、エラーが発生した時等にファイルが開き放しになってしまうので修正しておきました。

```
def get_kabu():
    csv_list = []

    time_ = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    csv_list.append(time_)
    url = "http://www.nikkei.com/markets/kabu/"
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    span = soup.find_all("span")
    nikkei_heikin = ""

    for tag in span:
        try:
            string_ = tag.get("class").pop(0)
            if string_ in "mkc-stock_prices":
                nikkei_heikin = tag.string
                break
        except:
            pass

    print (time_, nikkei_heikin)
    csv_list.append(nikkei_heikin)
    with open('nikkei_heiki.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(csv_list)

get_kabu()
```

また、BeautifulSoupは、tagと一緒にclassも検索できるので次のように簡単にかけます。

```
def get_kabu():
    time_ = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    url = "http://www.nikkei.com/markets/kabu/"
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    try:
        nikkei_heikin = soup.find("span", class_="mkc-stock_prices").text
    except AttributeError:
        nikkei_heikin = ""
    print (time_, nikkei_heikin)
    with open('nikkei_heiki.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([time_, nikkei_heikin])
```